# MongoDB. How to filter documents by nested array property?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var ParagraphsSchema = new Schema({
originalText: String,
suggestions: [{
    text: String,
    is_approved: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  }]
});
```

And the task is **to get paragraphs where all suggestions are not approved** 
(suggestion.is_approved = false)

I have already tried things like

```
Paragraph.find({ 'suggestions.is_approved': { $all: [false] })

Paragraph.find({'suggestions.is_approved': { $all: {"$elemMatch": false} } })
```

but none of them seem to work.

The obvious way would be to add "is_approved" property to Paragraph schema, but that would make data redundant and make code harder to maintain, that's why I would like to avoid it.

I'm using MongoDB==3.6.2 and Mongoose==5.0.3

Comment: Try this `Paragraph.find({'suggestions':{'$elemMatch':{'is_approved':false}}})`

Comment: Try `Paragraph.find({ "suggestions.is_approved": { $ne:true } })`

Comment: @Veeram thanks, this works like a charm! I also added `suggestions: { $gt: [] }` to get rid of paragraphs where no suggestions are present.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution that works for me (thanks to @Veeram's answer in comments). 
Here it is:

```
Paragraph.find({ 
       suggestions: { $gt: [] }, 
      'suggestions.is_approved':  { $ne: true } 
})
```

I added `suggestions: { $gt: [] }` to get rid of paragraphs where suggestions array is empty.